# beta decay of a growing sample

Tags: homework-and-exercises

This is an exercise about neutron capture. I want the remaining $^{198}$Au after a time t and I know $\lambda$.

$^{197}$Au absorps a neutron and transforms to $^{198}$Au which then decays.
The sample absorps 10$^{20}$ neutrons every second, but how do I include the decay for the atoms the sample gains every second?

Because for
N(t) = $C*e^{-t\lambda}+10^{20}*t$
wouldn't C = 0 because of N(0) = 0?

Edit: So I guess I have to solve the differential $N'(t) + \lambda N(t) = 10^{20} $

Comment: Search term: "secular equilibrium." Also, $10^{20}\rm\,s^{-1}$ is a *lot* of neutrons.

Comment: For the differential eq. I found $N(t) = N(0)e^{-\lambda t} + 10^{20}/\lambda $ Thank you for the tip, I keep thinking about it.

Comment: @rob that isn’t just a lot of neutrons. That’s 10x or more of the neutron dose for structural materials across the lifetime of a modern nuclear reactor...

Comment: The exercise was posed in class, maybe I didn't write it down correctly.:)

Comment: Speaking of lots of neutrons, check out https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/437245/what-would-happen-to-a-room-full-of-neutrons