# How does neutron radiation affects a body?

Tags: particle-physics, radiation, quantum-chromodynamics, neutrons, subatomic

My question involves two aspects of the same thing: how does neutron radiation affect the particles in our body.

• First of all: How does the effects happen, from a quantum perspective?

• Second, and more important: How does it work? I mean, how does the lonely neutron (chargeless particle) interacts with the particles it has contact with and how does this interaction affects a given system.

I guess it may involve the strong nuclear force between it and the nucleus of the target atom, but I have no clue of how does it affect the system and cause it's symptoms.

Comment: There's some relevant info on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_radiation). Scientists Harry Daghlian and Louis Slotin died of acute radiation poisoning caused by neutrons emitted in the [Demon Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_core) accidents.

Comment: Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/437245/123208 & the links there.

Comment: this is more a question for health physics, I would try https://biology.stackexchange.com/ . also you have to give context, what energy?  reactor neutrons? accelerator neutrons?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about physiology not physics

Comment: I am more concerned about not only the effects of the radiation itself, but what happens in a quantum level that affects the whole

Comment: Sorry, your question is still off-topic here. You need to ask a specific question that relates to the physics of neutron radiation. Is there some specific thing in the articles I linked earlier that you need help in understanding? As stated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_capture neutrons have no electric charge, so they can enter a nucleus more easily than positively charged protons, which are repelled electrostatically.