# Fast neutron scattering in a neutron cloud

Tags: energy, scattering, neutrons

Will a 200 MeV neutron emitted into a neutron cloud undergo similar scattering interactions as one that is emitted into a water moderator with the resulting decreases in energy?

Comment: A cloud of neutrons has a lot of energy. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/437245/123208

Comment: there are many parameters entering neutron matter interactions , see https://www.nrc.gov/docs/ML1122/ML11229A705.pdf